# Reactive Form setValue or patchValue not working RxJS Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

Hello Fellow Devs,

```
Why does my view doesn't update the view if i use the rxjs request
```

Here is a sample of the code:

So when i call the setManualValue it updates my view,but when i call the rxjs using http request
it doesn't

``

`
export class createClinicSevice{

```
  form:FormGroup;

  setManualValue=()=>{

    this.form.userName.setValue('It's working fine');

  }

  callRequest=()=>{
    this.createNewClinicRequestSubject.next();
  }

  private createNewClinicRequestSubject = new Subject();

  private testStream=()=>{

     this.createNewClinicRequestSubject.pipe(

      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),

      switchMap(() => {

        this.isLoading = true;

        return this.http.post<CreateClinic>(`${environment.apiUrl}/account` +
            `/createclinic`, this.createClinic);
      })
    ).subscribe((result: CreateClinic) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      if (result != null) {
        this.form.userName.setValue('this doesnt work!!!')
      }
    });
  }

}`
```

``

I am expecting that the value get's updated

Answer (score 0):

Please, format in a better way the code in order to follow the guidelines! Thank you!

I will leave just few considerations.

- `takeUntil` destroy must be always the last piped operator in order to avoid memory leaks
- Are you sure is only the view not updated? Which change detection strategy are you using? Have you tried to call `this.form.userName.updateValueAndValidity` after calling `setValue`? This will re-evaluate validation and will refresh the view.